# JQuery AJAX PUT method return 404 error (not found) in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

here is my problem, I try to use JQuery AJAX update my data in asp.net mvc, but when I use PUT method, it will return a error said 404, means it can not find my controller, but if I use GET/POST method, everything is working fine, so what's the problem? thanks!

```
var Test= {
    Update: function (TestId, Test, callback) {

        var errorMsg = "Missing a parameter!";
        if (!TestId) { throw errorMsg; return; }
        if (Test== null) { throw errorMsg; return; }
        if (callback == null) { throw errorMsg; return; }

        var pack = { "test" : Test};

        $.ajax({
            type: "PUT",
            url: "/test/" + TestId+ "/update",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(pack),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            processData: false,
            cache: false
        }).done(function (result) {
            callback(result);
        });

    }
};
```

Comment: Can you post the asp.net code which handles the request? Or at least some of it?

Comment: Check the request (for example in FireFox developer tools under network tab) and see the exact URL which is being called. You should be able to call your method manually by typing the correct path in URL bar. You can then compare both of them and see if your URL path is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set it to be a accept put on the .NET side?

```
[HttpPut]
public JsonResult Update(int id)
{
    return Json("Your Response");
}
```

Comment: Lacking [HttpPut] should yield a 404 error thou, right?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks a lot for your help! I found my problem, it was my iis configuration, seems lot of ppl have same problem, one solution is remove WebDav from your IIS, but this one not working for my case. another one is allow those http verbs on your server, this one work for my case, here is the link!
http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2011/05/28/resolve-404-in-iis-express-for-put-and-delete-verbs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should **never hard-code** **URLs** in `MVC`.

Instead use `@Url.Action`.

```
url: '@Url.Action("FunctionName", "ControllerName")',
```

If you wish to send parameters use

```
url: '@Url.Action("FunctionName", "ControllerName", new { ID = Model.MyID })',
```

Also, for the sake of your sanity, use the fail method.

```
$.ajax("http://url")
    .done(function() {
    alert("success");
})
    .fail(function() {
    alert("error");
})
```

If this doesn't fix your problem tell us what kind of error(s) are you getting.